# Font used in Munkres "Topology"

Tags: fonts, theorems

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me figure out what font Munkres used in his famous "Topology" book. I am interested in the font used in the main body as well as the font used in his "theorem" environment.

I searched the Internet for similar questions with no success. I also tried "myfonts.com," but that did not yield any satisfactory results. Finally, I looked at PDF version of his book and by going to "documents properties," I checked the fonts that the pdf viewer was able to detect. However, the results (mainly variations of Courier, Helvetica, and Times) do not look quite similar to what it really is.

The reason I am asking this question is that Munkres strikes me as an incredibly easy book to read and I would like to format my papers in a similar manner. As a example, his "f" in a theorem environment looks differently than his "f" in a math mode, which makes it extremely easy to distinguish between the two.

Below you can a few screenshots from his book.

Thank you for all your help.

EDIT: I understand that some of you may think it is a duplicate of 
[How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture), but I tried methods mentioned in that post and it did not solve my problem. However, thankfully some of you have already answered my question, which I am very grateful for.

[image: Example1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: It seems a Times clone.

Comment: Looks like it it possible that some kind of a variation of Times was used in the main body. However, his "theorem environment" does not use the italicized Times New Roman, since italicized "f" in Times New Roman looks much different.

Comment: Note that the theorem body font shape isn't italic but, rather, slanted-roman.

Comment: Determining the font of a printed document is an interesting question, but "his f in a theorem environment looks differently than his f in a math mode" makes it sound like you could be focusing on how the f in function is different than the f in f(x).  That's simply because the latter is in a math mode (surrounded by dollar signs); such an f is different in most fonts.  Compare f (regular) to *f* (italic) to $f$ (math mode in your TeX document).

Comment: @Teepeemm the default computer modern is an exception to that -- they're the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's definitely a Times font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{times,newtxmath}

\newtheoremstyle{slanted}
  {\topsep}%   Space above
  {\topsep}%   Space below
  {\slshape}%  Body font
  {}%          Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%         Punctuation after thm head
  {0.5em}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
     %         \newline = linebreak
  {}%          Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\theoremstyle{slanted}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{21}
\setcounter{theorem}{2}

The subject of topology is of interest in its own right,
and it serves also to lay the foundations for future studies
in analysis, in geometry, and in algebraic topology.
There is no universal agreement among mathematicians as to
what a first course in topology should include; there are
many topics that are appropriate to such a course, and not
all are equally relevant to these differing purposes.
In the choice of material to be treated, I~have tried to
strike a balance among the various points of view.

\begin{theorem}
Let $f:X\to Y$. If the function $f$ is continuous, then for
every convergent sequence $x_{n}\to x$ in~$X$, the sequence
$f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. The converse holds if $X$ is
metrizable.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Note that `newtxtext` has no slanted shape, so if you really want such a shape, you need `times`.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful answer! Thank you very much! I really appreciate the time and effort you put into answering my question.